# Define custom environment

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I'm currently writing a `.sty`-file that defines the look of assignment-sheets for students. I now want do define some custom environments for the questions and answers.

The answer blocks are printed inside of a `tcolorbox` and only shown, if a boolean is set to true. So in the definition of my custom environment I first check the boolean and then paste the `tcolorbox` opening tag.
Unfortunately this returns the following error:

> LaTeX Error: \begin{tcb@savebox} on input line 62 ended by \end{enumerate}.

Here is the code:

```
\newenvironment{solution}
    {
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{
            \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, width=\textwidth, colframe=red, colback=white]
    }
    {
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }{} 
    }
```

I used the code like this:

```
\begin{solution}
    \begin{align*}
        x^2 + y^2 &= z^2\\
        \Rightarrow x &= \sqrt{z^2 - y^2}\\
        &= ...
    \end{align*}
\end{solution}
```

What have I done wrong? Thank you very much in advance!

---

## Clarification

It seems that my question is a bit unclear, so I'm trying to explain it a little better by the use of the following picture. [image: example]

Note that the page on the left only displays the assignments and the page on the right also includes the solutions to the problems. What I want to do, is to be able to compile both of these documents out of one single `.tex` file. I don't want to have a file for the assignments and one for the solutions. In my preamble i want to set a boolean to either `true` or `false`. If the boolean `solution` is set to `false`, the solution should NOT be compiled, so the resulting document is the one on the left. If the `boolean` is set to `true`, the solutions should be compiled, so the resulting document is the one on the right.

The `solution`-environment I asked for should check if the `boolean` is set to `true` and if so, compile it's content.

Until now it worked if I coded like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
    %
    %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% Question
    \item Compute the Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
        %
        %
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        %% Solution
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{
            \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, width=\textwidth, colframe=red, colback=white]
                \begin{eqnarray*}
                    \hat{f}(\xi)&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}e^{-ix\xi}dx\\
                    &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x-ix\xi}dx+\int_{-\infty}^0e^{x-ix\xi}dx\\
                    &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-x-ix\xi}-e^{-x+ix\xi})dx\\
                    &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[\frac{1}{-(1+i\xi)}(-1)-\frac{1}{-1+i\xi}(-1)]\\
                    &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[\frac{1-i\xi}{1+\xi^2}+\frac{-(1+i\xi)}{1+\xi^2}]\\
                    &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{-2i\xi}{1+\xi^2}\\
                    &=&-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{i\xi}{1+\xi^2}
                \end{eqnarray*}
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }{}
    %
    %
    \item Compute the Fourier transform of $e^{-a|x|^2},~a>0$, directly, where $x\in \mathbb{R}$.\\
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{
            \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, width=\textwidth, colframe=red, colback=white]
                \begin{eqnarray*}
                    \hat{f}(\xi)&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a|x|^2}e^{-ix\xi}dx\\
                    &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a(x+\frac{i\xi}{2a})^2+\frac{-\xi^2}{4a}}dx~~~~~~~~x'\doteq x+\frac{i\xi}{2a}\\
                    &=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx\\
                    &=&\frac{e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4a}}}{2a}
                \end{eqnarray*}
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }{}
\end{enumerate}
```

The custom `solution`-environment should combine these two lines (and their closing tags) to make programming quicker and cleaner:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, width=\textwidth, colframe=red, colback=white]
```

Hopefully this clears up the misunderstandings. If you have any further question, feel free to ask. :)

Comment: Off-Topic: The `eqnarray*` environment is outdated

Comment: See the update please

Comment: To the off-topic: I'm actually using `align*`, I just copied this math code from the internet because I didn't want to write something out myself. **Back to the main question:** @ChristianHupfer, you're awesome!! This now really works as expected. Great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\ifthenelse` condition ends prematurely and leaves an open `environment` hanging around in the middle of nowhere.

In conjunction with `tcolorbox` environment, the end - delimiter is `\endtcolorbox` and I suggest to use two `\ifthenelse` statements, one for the `start` code of the environment and another one for the end code.

A better approach would use `\DeclareTColorbox`, in my opinion or a weird `\scantokens` construct.

Also possible: Use `\tcolorboxenvironment` to wrap around an existing `solution` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newboolean{solution}

\newenvironment{solution}{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{%
    \tcolorbox[breakable, width=\textwidth, colframe=red, colback=white]
    }{%
  }%
}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{\endtcolorbox}{}}


\begin{document}

\setboolean{solution}{true}
\begin{solution}
  \begin{align*}
    x^2 + y^2 &= z^2\\
    \Rightarrow x &= \sqrt{z^2 - y^2}\\
    &= ...
  \end{align*}
\end{solution}

\setboolean{solution}{false}
\begin{solution}
  \begin{align*}
    x^2 + y^2 &= z^2\\
    \Rightarrow x &= \sqrt{z^2 - y^2}\\
    &= ...
  \end{align*}
\end{solution}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Cleaner solution with two different environments**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\tcbset{
  commonboxes/.style={nobeforeafter},
  nobox/.style={commonboxes,blank,breakable},
  solutionbox/.style={commonboxes,breakable, colframe=red, colback=white}
}


\newtcolorbox{solutionbox}[1][]{
  solutionbox,#1
}

\newtcolorbox{solutionbox*}[1][]{%
  nobox,#1
}






\begin{document}

\begin{solutionbox*}
  \begin{align*}
    x^2 + y^2 &= z^2\\
    \Rightarrow x &= \sqrt{z^2 - y^2}\\
    &= ...
  \end{align*}
\end{solutionbox*}

\begin{solutionbox}
  \begin{align*}
    x^2 + y^2 &= z^2\\
    \Rightarrow x &= \sqrt{z^2 - y^2}\\
    &= ...
  \end{align*}
\end{solutionbox}



\end{document}
```

**Third installment of a solution with `\NewEnviron` and the `\BODY` command.**

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newboolean{solution}

\tcbset{
 commonboxes/.style={nobeforeafter,breakable},
  nobox/.style={commonboxes,blank,breakable},
  solutionbox/.style={commonboxes,breakable, colframe=red, colback=white}
}


\NewEnviron{solution}[1][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{%
    \tcolorbox[solutionbox, width=\textwidth,#1]
    \BODY
    }{%
  }%
}[\ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{\endtcolorbox}{}]





\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}]
\item Compute the Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
  \begin{solution}[colframe=blue]
    \begin{align*}
      \hat{f}(\xi)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}e^{-ix\xi}dx\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x-ix\xi}dx+\int_{-\infty}^0e^{x-ix\xi}dx\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-x-ix\xi}-e^{-x+ix\xi})dx\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[\frac{1}{-(1+i\xi)}(-1)-\frac{1}{-1+i\xi}(-1)]\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[\frac{1-i\xi}{1+\xi^2}+\frac{-(1+i\xi)}{1+\xi^2}]\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{-2i\xi}{1+\xi^2}\\
      &=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{i\xi}{1+\xi^2}
    \end{align*}
  \end{solution}             
\item Compute the Fourier transform of $e^{-a|x|^2},~a>0$, directly, where $x\in \mathbb{R}$.\\
  \begin{solution}
    \begin{align*}
      \hat{f}(\xi)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a|x|^2}e^{-ix\xi}dx\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a(x+\frac{i\xi}{2a})^2+\frac{-\xi^2}{4a}}dx~~~~~~~~x'\doteq x+\frac{i\xi}{2a}\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx\\
      &=\frac{e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4a}}}{2a}
    \end{align*}
  \end{solution}

\end{enumerate}

\setboolean{solution}{true}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}]
\item Compute the Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
  \begin{solution}[colframe=blue]
    \begin{align*}
      \hat{f}(\xi)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-|x|}e^{-ix\xi}dx\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x-ix\xi}dx+\int_{-\infty}^0e^{x-ix\xi}dx\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-x-ix\xi}-e^{-x+ix\xi})dx\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[\frac{1}{-(1+i\xi)}(-1)-\frac{1}{-1+i\xi}(-1)]\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[\frac{1-i\xi}{1+\xi^2}+\frac{-(1+i\xi)}{1+\xi^2}]\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{-2i\xi}{1+\xi^2}\\
      &=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{i\xi}{1+\xi^2}
    \end{align*}
  \end{solution}             
\item Compute the Fourier transform of $e^{-a|x|^2},~a>0$, directly, where $x\in \mathbb{R}$.\\
  \begin{solution}
    \begin{align*}
      \hat{f}(\xi)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a|x|^2}e^{-ix\xi}dx\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a(x+\frac{i\xi}{2a})^2+\frac{-\xi^2}{4a}}dx~~~~~~~~x'\doteq x+\frac{i\xi}{2a}\\
      &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx\\
      &=\frac{e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{4a}}}{2a}
    \end{align*}
  \end{solution}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The `\BODY` command contains the environment 'text' and is printed only in the case `solution` is true.

Comment: Works fine, but the `tcolorbox` doesn't do page-breaks anymore. As you see, I had the argument `breakable` in my previous code. I also used `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}` to allow page breaks which worked. Now with the new `\begin{solution}`-environment, it doesn't perform the breaks anymore. How could I fix this? PS: I used your first method.

Comment: @Sam: I forgot the `breakable` option in the `nobox` style, I've added it to the second solution, it can be used in `commonboxes` style as well, since it should apply to all boxes of this kind.

Comment: No, I'm using your very first solution,  not the cleaner one.

Comment: @Sam: well, I tried the first solution and the breaking works for me.

Comment: But I can also switch to the clean version, if that's better, but I don't understand how I can switch between assignment-sheet and solution-sheet. With the first version I can simply set the boolean to `true` and then the solutions are printed. If set to `false`
, only the assignments are printed. That's very neat. But I don't see how this is done by your clean version with the two environments.

Comment: @Sam: I'll try to add a different solution later on

Comment: Maybe, using `code={\ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{\tcbset{solutionbox}}{\tcbset{nobox}}}` is another alternative, if the boolean switch is important for the OP?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I fixed the issue, where the page break didn’t work, but I noticed, that your code does not work as expected. You see, in your solution, you wrote a code that hides the ˋtcolorboxˋ if the boolean is set to false, but the answer to the assignment is still printed out. I didn’t notice this 2 days ago because I was too focused on the pagebreak. What I‘m trying to get is an environment that includes the answer to an assignement and that answer should only be printed out if the boolean is set to true. In all other case the whole ˋ\begin{solution}ˋ should be ignored while compiling.

Comment: @Sam: Your question gets unclear to me...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I edited my question to clear things up :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you wrote:

```
\newenvironment{solution}
    {% open 1
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{% open 2
            \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, width=\textwidth, colframe=red, colback=white]
    }% close 1
    {% open 3
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }{}% close 2, open & close 4
    }% close 3
```

But this is mixing open and closed (and TeX doesn’t look at indentation).
Here is the code TeX sees:

```
\newenvironment{solution}
    {% open 1
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{% open 2
            \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, width=\textwidth, colframe=red, colback=white]
        }% close 2
        {% open 3
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }{}% close 3, open & close 4
    }% close 1
```

And of course, this doesn’t make sense.  The environment is missing its second argument; if `solution`, then the tcolorbox opens (but never closes); if not `solution`, then the tcolorbox closes (but never opened).   And `{}` #4 does nothing.  Something more along the lines of your original would be:

```
\newenvironment{solution}
    {% open 1
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{% open 2
            \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, width=\textwidth, colframe=red, colback=white]
        }{% close 2, open 3
            \begin{comment}
        }% close 3
    }% close 1
    {% open 4
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{solution}}{% open 5
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }{% close 5, open 6
            \end{comment}
        }% close 6
    }% close 4
```

where we use the `comment` package to discard the answer.  (You may want to use different variable names, so that `solution` isn't an environment and a boolean.)

Comment: How is this different to my first solution?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Unfortunately it's not different to your's at all.

Comment: @Teepeemm I see wat my mistake was, that caused the error, but it still does not answer the main issue.

Comment: Took me awhile to spot the "main issue".  I've added the comment environment to discard the solution when necessary.